# Get RGB pixel data of a section of a screen as an array in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame2

My code allows a user to draw on a section of a pygame screen. I want to be able to extract **all** the RGB pixel values for this section of the screen and convert them to a 3d array, like this:

```
top_left = [50, 50]
bottom_right = [100, 100]
pixel_data = SomeFunctionToGetPixelData(screen, top_left, bottom_right)

# get RGB value for pixel that was at position (53, 51) on the screen
print(pixel_data[3][1])
> [255, 255, 255]
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subsurface from the section of the screen. A subsurface shares its pixels with its new parent (see [`pygame.Surface.subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface)):

```py
w = bottom_right[0] - top_left[0]
h = bottom_right[1] - top_left[1]
area = pygame.Rect(top_left[0], top_left[1], w, h)
sub_surface = screen.subsurface(area)
```

Use [`pygame.surfarray.array3d()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.array3d) to copy the pixels from a *Surface* into a 3D array:

```py
pixel_data = pygame.surfarray.array3d(sub_surface)
```

---

Minimal function:

```py
def get_pixel_data(surf, top_left, bottom_right):
    w = bottom_right[0] - top_left[0]
    h = bottom_right[1] - top_left[1]
    sub_surface = surf.subsurface(pygame.Rect(*top_left, w, h))
    return pygame.surfarray.array3d(sub_surface)
```